# Using mockito with wildcard agruments

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to pass wildcard into mockito any() method.
This is the method

```
selectGatewayInfoConfig(Operation<?> o)
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
when(gatewayConfigSelector.selectGatewayInfoConfig( any(**!!!!!! HERE I NEED THIS WILDCARD !!!!**));
                .thenReturn(...something...);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

How about?

```
when(gatewayConfigSelector.selectGatewayInfoConfig( any(Operation.class));
            .thenReturn(...something...);
```

Example:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Tester mock = Mockito.mock(Tester.class);
    Mockito.when(mock.selectGatewayInfoConfig(Mockito.any(Operation.class))).thenReturn("blah");

    System.out.println(mock.selectGatewayInfoConfig(null));
}


class Operation<T> {

}

class Tester {

    public String selectGatewayInfoConfig(Operation<?> o) {
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the method selectGatewayInfoConfig in Tester class is not a part of tested code, where the WHEN condition should apply.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your comment. The class you're mocking is usually because it's not what you want to test - it's what you want to mock out. As long as the class is on your classpath and not final you should be able to mock it as above. Is this a void return type method? If so the when() needs to be written a little differently. Otherwise using an any(Operation.class) matcher should be fine.